# i have a problem with mdns i'm using an ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I am working on a project on which I have to drive a DC 12V motor. I use an ESP8266 I manage to manage my engine remotely but my only problem is the mdns I use the mdns but it does not work. when I upload no error is displayed but I can not access my esp using his name.local

Comment: what esp8266 boards package version? PC has Windows or Linux?

Comment: I use the ESP12E and the version of my arduino is 1.8.9 my driving board is the pololu and my pc is on linux

Comment: sorry i forgot, i use linux on my pc